# Перенос строки кода Java

Tags: java

Читаю мою первую книгу по программированию и возник вопрос по переносу кода. Погуглил,рекомендуют переносить каждый параметр на отдельную строку. Не могли бы вы объяснить как сделать перенос строки в моем случае ? После (WorkoutDetailFragment) ? Или перед точкой ? Как принято для удобства чтения ?

[image: перенос строки кода]

```
package com.example.workout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
        frag.setWorkoutId(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще `CTRL+ALT+L` автоматически выровняют ваш код, если вы где-то его криво написали.

Answer (score 3):

Есть разные стили форматирования кода.

Примеры:

- https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.htm
- https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/code-style
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf
- https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/JavaStyle.html

Можно посмотреть на правила форматирования и делать, как там написано, но они, честно говоря, не всегда очевидны. Более практичным является использования возможности IDE. Конкретно в IntelliJ для стиля от google (а также android) можно подключить плагин google-java-format и тогда автоматическое форматирование, которое делает IDE будет соответствовать правилам одного из этих стилей.

Для начала установите плагин:

[image: плагин google-java-format в intellij]

А потом включите его:

[image: включение плагина]

После этого IDE автоматически будет форматировать новый код, а существующий можно отформатировать с помощью пункта меню `Code -> Reformat Code`.

Конкретно этот кусок кода согласно google java code style форматируется так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
  WorkoutDetailFragment frag =
      (WorkoutDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
  frag.setWorkoutId(1);
}
```